# How can I run appRunWar in a port other than the one defined in the build.gradle

Tags: java, gretty

I' having issues while trying to change the port for Gretty as indicated in the Gretty documentation.

```
Gradle appRunWar -PhttpPort=8888
```

The only way it works is by changing the build.gradle gretty block

```
gretty {
    http = 8888
    contextPath = '/'
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  This sounds like a bug report to the Gretty development team.

Comment: Correct, It is reported in the following 
https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after searching the Gretty [Possible Running Build in Different Ports](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/195) Github repository.

All you need to do is change the build.gradle file as follows

```
gretty {
    httpPort = project.hasProperty("httpPort") ? project.httpPort as int : 8080
    contextPath = '/'
}
```

Another way to do this is by adding the following

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    graph ->
        if (project.hasProperty("httpPort")) {
            gretty.httpPort = httpPort as int
        }
}
```

Both solutions will work by passing property arguments to the guild file

```
 gradle -PhttpPort=8888
```